# How can I execute a .jar file from the terminal

Tags: command-line, java

I know that to execute a file, I use the `.` command, then the file name with a space between them. But I'm trying to execute a .jar file using the `.` and it does not work. I went into the properties and marked it as executable and made it run with Java.

Is there a way to execute a file with Java in the **Bash** Terminal? 
[image: I am trying to execute a Minecraft.jar file]

I am trying to execute the Minecraft.jar file.

Comment: Hello and welcome, jaorizabal. I slightly corrected your question. Maybe you can install a spell checker for your browser, to improve the next question yourself. Another hint: For text issues, you may mark text with your mouse in the terminal, and then paste it into the edit field of your browser (and elsewhere) with a middle click on the scroll wheel. Then you can layout your code with the buttons at the edit field. This is much faster than taking a screen shot, and uploading it.

Answer (score 308, accepted):

The `.` syntax can only be used to run (by "sourcing") shell scripts.

You'll need to use the `java` command to run a `.jar` file:

```
java -jar Minecraft.jar
```

If you don't have java installed, you can fix that by installing the `default-jre`¹ package. You can see if you already have java installed by running in a terminal:

```
java -version
```

[1]: This will install the default openjdk Java runtime. You can use `openjdk-8-jre`, or `openjdk-7-jre`, or `openjdk-6-jre` instead, if you prefer - whichever is available on your version of Ubuntu.

Comment: `$ java -jar schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar 
*** Required parameter '-o' was not specified. ***
`

Answer (score 43):

Linux is perfectly capable of running a foreign binary, like a JAR file. This is how Wine works, for example. To run JAR files as executable do the following in a console

```
sudo apt-get install binfmt-support
```

Cd to your JAR file and change it to executable (you can also do this through file properties in Nautilus)

```
chmod a+rx myjar.jar
```

Run your jar file just as if it was any other binary executable or shell script

```
./myjar.jar
```

Note: Be sure you have **binfmt_misc** linux kernel module loaded. If you use your custom compiled kernel without this module, binfmt-support won't work.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. It's better than using java -jar because it doesn't require the host program to know that it is a java program, and it's better than using a script because you don't have to worry about passing through STDIN and OUT.

Comment: Doesn't work on Debian 9: "invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error"

Answer (score 20):

If it is an executable jar, then

```
java -jar Minecraft.jar
```

Not all jar-Archives contain an executable class, declared to be started in the Manifest file, but if there is, this will work.

Btw.: You don't start most programs from the shell with the dot. The dot is a shortcut for `source`, and it only works in the bash and some other shells, to include a script in the scope of the current session.

A compiled binary xybin is simply started with its name if it is in the path:

```
xybin
```

or, with its absolute path:

```
/home/foo/proj/test/xybin
```

or with its relative path:

```
proj/test/xybin
```

or if you happen to be in the directory of the file, with this relative path:

```
./xybin
```

The file has to be marked executable for you (see: chmod).
All of the above is true for shellscripts too, but they often have an extension .sh, and you can start a shellscript by invoking the interpreter, and then it needn't be marked executable:

```
 bash xy.sh
```

If you don't want to start a new bash, you can use source, and you do so, to consume function definitions, aliases and variable settings.

Answer (score 9):

You might as well want to make a nice entry for the application in Unity. execute the following commands:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/minecraft.desktop
```

In the window that pops up, copy and paste the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Minecraft
Comment=Click here to play Minecraft
Exec=java -jar /path/to/minecraft.jar
Icon=/path/to/minecraft/icon.png
Terminal=false
Categories=Game;
```

You might need to log out and back in to see the effects. :) Also you need to search the internet for a nice lookin Minecraft icon since they don't provide one with the download..

Answer (score 5):

1. Open a command prompt with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Go to your ".jar" file directory. If your Ubuntu version / flavour supports it, you should be able to right click on your ".jar" file's directory and click "Open in Terminal"
3. Type the following command:

   ```
   java -jar jarfilename.jar
   ```

This way your ".jar" file will execute.

Answer (score 5):

Install jarwrapper. After that (and by adding the executable bit) you can start the jar file just by entering the jarfile name.

```
sudo apt-get install jarwrapper
```

This works by using `binfmt` to add support for a new binary format to the kernel.

Answer (score 3):

```
 java -jar /home/username/.minecraft/launcher.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

*New answer to an old question*

Executing a jar file using the regular syntax `./app.jar` (instead of `java -jar`), is easy to achieve, as explained here: [how to create executable jars](https://dev.to/derlin/how-to-create-jars-that-run-like-any-other-executable-binary-appjar-ic3).

Basically, JAR is a variant of ZIP, which allows random bytes to be pre/appended to the JAR without corrupting it. This means it is possible to prepend a launcher script at the beginning of the jar to make it "executable".

Here is a simple example of turning a "normal" jar into an executable one:

```bash
# Append a basic launcher script to the jar
cat \
  <(echo '#!/bin/sh')\
  <(echo 'exec java -jar $0 "$@"')\
  <(echo 'exit 0')\
  original.jar > executable.jar

# Make the new jar executable
chmod +x executable.jar
```

With this, you can now run `./executable.jar` instead of `java -jar original.jar`. This works on all **unix like systems** including Linux, MacOS, Cygwin, and Windows Linux subsystem.

Answer (score -1):

if u want to install your jar with specific java version
Specify the java directory also

```
/scratch/app/product/Software/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java -jar /path-to-jar/Minecraft.jar
```