# Some jar files refuse to to run upon double-click and Terminal can't access them

Tags: command-line, java, jar

MultiMC launches with no problems. I can't get Minecraft to launch by double-clicking it: it will open in Archive Manager. When I run the command `java -jar minecraft.jar`, Terminal returns the error `Error: Unable to access jarfile minecraft.jar`.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/101746/how-can-i-execute-a-jar-file-from-the-terminal?rq=1 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/192914/how-run-a-jar-file-with-a-double-click?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Both things are happening because `minecraft.jar` is not marked as executable by your user; assuming that you are the owner of the file, run this command from the command-line to mark it as executable by you:

```
chmod u+x <path_to_jar_file>
```

<sub>*<path_to_jar_file> = full path to the `.jar` file</sub>

If you want it to be run from the member of your user's group as well, run this instead:

```
chmod ug+x <path_to_jar_file>
```

<sub>*<path_to_jar_file> = full path to the `.jar` file</sub>

If you want it to be run from anyone, run this instead:

```
chmod a+x <path_to_jar_file>
```

<sub>*<path_to_jar_file> = full path to the `.jar` file</sub>

If you're not the owner, you can own the file and set its group to your user's group by running this command:

```
chown <username>:<username> <path_to_jar_file>
```

<sub>*<username> = you user's username; <path_to_jar_file> = full path to the `.jar` file</sub>

Comment: now it says that the file or path doesn't exist.

Comment: @PirosStaccatta Then you're typing the wrong path. The most straightforward way to get the correct path is to drag and drop the executable in the Terminal's window.

Comment: that's odd.  I marked it as executable every time I downloaded it. I must not be the owner then

Comment: @PirosStaccatta You can own the file by running `sudo chown <username>:<username> <path_to_jar_file>` (where `<username>` = your username)

Comment: @PirosStaccatta Also if something is still wrong please add the output of `ls -l <path_to_jar_file>` to your question by editing the question's body