# Executing file with other application through terminal

Tags: jre

Is there any way for me to execute a .jar file with JRE through the command line. I'm having an issue with the file and I wanna see if I can get any information as to what the error is. When I try to execute it with ./ it says that that it can't execute binary file.  But the icon gives me the option to run with Java Runtime Environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I execute a .jar file from the terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/101746/how-can-i-execute-a-jar-file-from-the-terminal)

Comment: @Danibix: Generic Unix administration questions are on topic here as long as they (may) occur in relation to a supported Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, the dote `.` can only be used to run shell scripts.

So you have to use **java** command to run `.jar` files

```
java -jar your_file_name.jar
```

That's it !

Comment: THANK YOU! It also inadvertently fixed the error as the script re downloaded a cache that  was causing the issue!

Answer (score 0):

**You have to run it though the JRE, not directly. ie.** `java -jar myapp.jar`

---

`./` Is not actually a command to run a program/script/binary. It simply refers to the current directory. For example, if I have a script, `myscript.sh`, in my home directory;

I can either run `./myscript.sh` or `/home/myusername/myscript.sh`

Both of those would run the script.

The reason why you couldn't just run `myscript.sh` is because the termnal would try to interprit it as a known command, and throw this error: `myscript.sh: command not found` because it isn't smart enough to know that you were trying to direct it to a file in your current `dir`.