# Running executable jar file from terminal

Tags: 16.04, python, java, executable, jar

I've just got a new PC running Ubuntu 16.04 and have transferred my work from my laptop running Ubuntu 14.04.

I have an executable jar file called timed_hri.jar.

On my laptop I can go to the directory and type ./timed_hri.jar and it runs. However, on my desktop it doesn't, I need this to run as I have a Python script that relies on using the ./ command on the file.

This is the output when I try it on my PC:

```
./timed_hri.jar: line 1: $'PK\003\004': command not found
./timed_hri.jar: line 2: $'\bne\355H': command not found
./timed_hri.jar: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token    `$'NX\252\276!\227\230iP\275餰  \364g\354\002aF\325\\\213G\263\225\3021B\305Q\237\336\337\375\301t\367\315 N?\372\275Z\235\031BB\3452/\231\241\266\377Z''
./timed_hri.jar: line 3:me�H6�8��META-INF/MANIFEST.MFM��!{��R
                                                              ȝƨ�!51��֬�^C�˂�/VZ��{(NX��!��iP�餰�g�aF�\�G���1B�Q�����t��N?��Z�BB�2/����Z'
```

Comment: Try running `java -jar ./timed_hri.jar`

Comment: Yeah, it works with that. Is there something I can do to get the direct ./ command to work on its own back?

Comment: ^ particularly @David 's answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/291514/546208

Comment: Thanks for your help! I hadn't seen that question in my searches.  David's response worked, I can now do ./ :). How do I mark your answer as correct?

Comment: If an answer in a different question helped you, upvoting it will help future users to more easily find the same answer.