# Java says it isn't installed!

Tags: command-line, software-installation, java

I'm installing Java and I am following instructions since Ubuntu Linux is new to me. I don't have enough "reputation" to post a lot of links, so I made a slideshow explaining it. Does anyone more experienced than me know how to do this?

[Click this to see slideshow](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/12Y7iwjIKojAox9JmdCT-B1PFTSFnq2Lm417_2UewjQk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you just looking for the java runtime?

Comment: No, java so I can run .jar files.

Comment: You should already have everything you need for that - that is the runtime environment - see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/101746/how-can-i-execute-a-jar-file-from-the-terminal)

Comment: So, Java Runtime Environment IS what you're looking for. Do not go that route: It's painful, time consuming and fraught with danger. You can install Java support from the official repositories.

Comment: If I type java into the command line it says: The program java can be found in the following packages......

Comment: In general, it is preferable to install software through Ubuntu's software repositories instead of going to a website and downloading it. L.D. James's answer tells you how to install Java from the repositories with one terminal command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bring up a `terminal` screen by typing `terminal` in the Ubuntu Dash Search.  Then run this on the commandline (the dollar sign is the command prompt you see in the terminal):

```
$ sudo apt install default-jre
```

The image you posted is giving that as a suggestion.