# how to run .jar software on ubuntu (17.04)?

Tags: command-line, java, openjdk

Despite following [the recommended command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101746/how-can-i-execute-a-jar-file-from-the-terminal) for .jar file :

```
java -jar imker-cli.jar
```

It doesn't work for me :

```
me@pc:~/Documents/imker$   java -jar imker-cli.jar
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
 * gcj-5-jre-headless
 * gcj-6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

What is going on ? What should I do to run this .jar file ?

Comment: See top answer: "*If you don't have java installed, you can fix that by installing the `default-jre` package.*"

Comment: oh ! I understood the error message as "you already have java in the following packages: [...]". Thanks to your comments I understand I must install it. Thanks !

Comment: @wjandrea it's not a duplicate of that, as they're already doing `java -jar`, which is the answer to that.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex The top answer also describes how to install Java.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you got ask you to install java. Run :

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

and it should work.