# Running jar files without using Java command

Tags: command-line, java

In console running a `jar` file is normally done by `java -jar application.jar`  Is there a way to run jar files by executing `./application.jar`? I'd like this behaviour for any `jar` file. I tried `chmod +x application.jar` but it won't work as it gives the following `error: invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error`. Further, it would be specific to one application.

Comment: Maybe makefile might help here!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: See my answer menteith!

Comment: Use binfmt-misc, but with `':ExecutableJAR:E::jar::/usr/local/bin/jarwrapper:'` instead of `:CLR:M::MZ::/usr/bin/mono:`, where `jarwrapper` essentially runs `java -jar "$@"`. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Binfmt_misc_for_Java for more

Comment: Or simpler: https://askubuntu.com/a/978003/158442

Comment: @muru Thanks for this. I installed `jarwrapper` but when I enter `./myjarfile.jar` zsh shows this error: `zsh: permission denied: ./myjarfile.jar`.  After that I created `/etc/binfmt.d/ExecutableJAR.conf ` with the following content `:ExecutableJAR:E::jar::/usr/bin/jarwrapper:`. I changed the path to `jarwrapper` because `which jarwrapper` shows `/usr/bin/jarwrapper`. Then I reboot my system. After that I'm still getting `zsh: permission denied: ./myjarfile.jar`.  What's wrong?

Comment: @menteith is the file executable? You still need it to be executable

Comment: It works after setting the file executable. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

.jar file is not executable by itself.. its just a modified(compiled and ziped) text file; the executable is the /usr/bin/java which sits on a path known to the system; that is why you can type **java -jar app.jar** and it works

`./command` means this folder in another shell loaded in this one(the command shell);

`. command` means this folder this shell

http://www.linfo.org/dot_slash.html

you can define an alias for the repetitive part `java -jar`

**temporary**

type `alias` inside a terminal to see already defined aliases

type your presumed alias to see if it returns command not found so you can use it

then type `alias command='java -jar'` to define the alias

after that you can use it as `command app.jar`

**permanent**

edit the `.bashrc` file from your home folder and add an alias like the one in **temporary** save and exit and relog

http://www.linfo.org/alias.html