# Passing a JAR to the Java runtime for Burpsuite

Tags: java

I want to start BurpSuite, not by double-clicking on the application to get it working but I want to start from the terminal by passing a JAR to the Java runtime.I use Java 8 and Burp Suite community edition (latest).

In one book it is written to provide in the terminal (passing a JAR to the Java runtime)
`java -jar /path/to/burpSuite.jar`, 
which when I am typing in terminal giving output 
`Error: Unable to access jarfile /path/to/burpSuite.jar`.
Now my system has a `burpsuite_community.jar` file inside or the path is 
`/home/user/BurpSuiteCommunity/burpsuite_community.jar`
**My question is what should my final command in the terminal** (getting confused due to `*/path/to*` -part given in the book.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I execute a .jar file from the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101746/how-can-i-execute-a-jar-file-from-the-terminal) - user unknown's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be:

```
java -jar /home/$USER/BurpSuiteCommunity/burpsuite_community.jar
```

I user $USER here; That is a variable that will change it into the current username. `echo $USER` will show you what this is. You can change that for your actual user name if you want.

This ...

```
/path/to/burpSuite.jar
```

you are suppose to change to your situation.